# Estimate transient power of crowbar circuit

Tags: protection, energy, transient

I am designing a crowbar circuit and for this circuit it is important that the maximal transient energy that goes through the circuit before the fuse trips stays below a certain limit. The setup of the circuit is as follows:

[image]

How can I, by using parameters available from the datasheets of the components give an estimation of the amount of energy that passes through the circuit when the high dc voltage is placed upon the circuit?

I don't need the exact value but just want to see if I can make a rough estimation. What components are expected to create the most delay, does the Zener diode delay have to be taken into account compared to the Thyristor delay. The output waveform of the current can be expected to look as follows:

[image]

Comment: You should simulate this wit LTSpice, this is the fastest way to have a result.

Comment: Or simulate with micro-cap. LTspice isn't the only game in town

Comment: Do fuses and thyristor models in LTSpice inhabit this kind of transient behavior accurately? And there is no way to check the result by hand by for example combinig the I^2t rating of the fuse with the dI/dt rating of the thyristor?